# CSS: align: justify and white-space: pre-wrap

Tags: css, whitespace, text-alignment

I am not able justify text with usage of white-space:pre-wrap;

```
<?php
 $mytext = 'The global race towards superfast "fifth generation" mobile internet, known as 5G, is entering a key phase. The trouble is no-one knows exactly which technologies will be best for offering such a service. But one telecoms firm may just have had a light-bulb moment.

            At its headquarters in Slough, O2 has installed an unusual demo. It is a room where a wireless internet connection is provided not through wi-fi, but li-fi - a system that transmits data through light waves rather than radio waves.

            The mobile operator thinks the system may help to offer 5G speeds in certain locations where getting coverage from an outdoor mobile signal is difficult.';
?>
    <p id="idtext" style="text-align: justify;white-space:pre-wrap;overflow-wrap: break-word;"><?php echo(trim($mytext));?></p>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `white-space: pre-wrap` doesn't work well with `text-align:justify`. Use `<br>` in the text instead.

Comment: The input is often user generated and so I fear there is little handle on editing the content to use <br>

Comment: `echo trim(str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $mytext));`